# Spline graph + column chart combo issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: Here is the image]

I'd like the spline to start and end at week 12. As you can see it falls short at week 11. I'm not sure why as there are 12 numerical values there in the js.

```
type: 'spline',
            name: 'Forecast',
            color: '#ff0000',
            data: [90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90,90, 90]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the line extends beyond the x axis min, to the left.

Need to see the rest of your code, or a fiddle, but I would assume you've done something like set your `xAxis` `min` property to `1`?

Your array of values will start at zero.

You can either

1) not set a `min` value on your x axis, and use categories to provide your labels of 1-52

or

2) keep the `min` of 1, and provide the `x` values in your data array (as it is, with only the `y` values, the start is always `0`)

Example with categories:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/185/

Answer (score 0):

it starts at 0, so the first value would be 0 (week) and the 12th value would be 11th week

either do minus 1 for the weeks in your code or add a thirteenth value.